# Android: Magento - Customer password not updating

Tags: android, magento, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am creating a shopping app which is using Magento Api to parse the data. I want to update the customer information (first name, last name, email id, password) using the [api](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.update.html). I am using the following code to change the information

```
..
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
..
..
SoapObject customerEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerCustomerEntityToCreate");
            customerEntity.addProperty("customerId",customerId);
            customerEntity.addProperty("email", email);
            customerEntity.addProperty("firstname", fname);
            customerEntity.addProperty("lastname", lname);
            customerEntity.addProperty("website_id", 1);
            customerEntity.addProperty("store_id", 1);
            customerEntity.addProperty("group_id",1);
            customerEntity.addProperty("password", strings[5]);
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerCustomerUpdate");
            request.addProperty("sessionId", envelope.getResponse().toString());
            request.addProperty("customerId", customerId);
            request.addProperty("customerData", customerEntity);

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            transportSE.debug = true;
            transportSE.call("", envelope);
```

The above code is returning me true and updating the first name, last name and email id but not password. Do we have to do something special for updating the password?